Getting TypeError when using FK in my Django Rest code (nested json)
I am trying to use a model as a Foreign key in another model and the result will be a nested json file , so when I modified my code to support it when I call the API using postman I get the following error:
typeId = self.request.data.pop("type_id")
KeyError: 'type_id'

Here is My code :
Models:
from django.db import models

############################
#Org_type related Models
############################

class Org_type(models.Model): 
    
    org_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.org_type

############################
#Organization related Models
############################
class Organization(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Org_type, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    unit_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subscription = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    credit_card = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    card_exp_date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    card_cvv =  models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


and here is my Serializers:
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Organization , Role_category , Org_type

############################
#Org_type related serializers
############################      
class Org_typeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Org_type
        fields = ['id','org_type', 'description','is_active']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Org_type` instance, given the validated data.
        """        
        type = Org_type.objects.create(
            org_type = validated_data['org_type'],
            description = validated_data['description'],
            is_active = validated_data['is_active'],
              
        )
    
        return type 
    
     
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Org_type` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.org_type = validated_data.get('org_type', instance.org_type)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.is_active = validated_data.get('is_active', instance.is_active)
        instance.save()
        return instance

############################
#Organization related serializers
############################
class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = Org_typeSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ['id','name','type', 'address', 'unit_no','city','province','country','zip','email','phone1',
                  'phone2','subscription','credit_card','card_exp_date','card_cvv','is_active']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `organization` instance, given the validated data.
        """        
        org = Organization.objects.create(
            name = validated_data['name'],
            type = validated_data['type'],
            address = validated_data['address'],
            unit_no = validated_data['unit_no'],
            city = validated_data['city'],
            province = validated_data['province'],
            country = validated_data['country'],
            zip = validated_data['zip'],
            email = validated_data['email'],
            phone1 = validated_data['phone1'],
            phone2 = validated_data['phone2'],
            subscription = validated_data['subscription'],
            credit_card = validated_data['credit_card'],
            card_exp_date = validated_data['card_exp_date'],
            card_cvv = validated_data['card_cvv'],
            is_active = validated_data['is_active'],
              
            
        )
    
        return org
    
     
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `organization` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        
       
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.type = validated_data.get('type', instance.type)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.unit_no = validated_data.get('unit_no', instance.unit_no)
        instance.city = validated_data.get('city', instance.city)
        instance.province = validated_data.get('province', instance.province)
        instance.country = validated_data.get('country', instance.country)
        instance.zip = validated_data.get('zip', instance.zip)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.phone1 = validated_data.get('phone1', instance.phone1)
        instance.phone2 = validated_data.get('phone2', instance.phone2)
        instance.subscription = validated_data.get('subscription', instance.subscription)
        instance.credit_card = validated_data.get('credit_card', instance.credit_card)
        instance.card_exp_date = validated_data.get('card_exp_date', instance.card_exp_date)
        instance.card_cvv = validated_data.get('card_cvv', instance.card_cvv)
        instance.is_active = validated_data.get('is_active', instance.is_active)
        instance.save()

        return instance



and here is the view:
############################
# Organization related views
############################
class OrganizationList(APIView):
    """
    List all organization, or create a new organization.
    """
    permission_calsses = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        org = Organization.objects.all()
        serializer = OrganizationSerializer(org, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = OrganizationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            typeId = self.request.data.pop("type_id")
            company_instance = Org_type.objects.filter(id=typeId).first()
            serializer.save(Org_type=company_instance)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class OrganizationDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a organization instance.
    """
    permission_calsses = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Organization.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Organization.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        org = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = OrganizationSerializer(org)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        org = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = OrganizationSerializer(org, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            typeId = self.request.data.pop("type_id")
            company_instance = Org_type.objects.filter(id=typeId).first()
            serializer.save(Org_type=company_instance)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        org = self.get_object(pk)
        org.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)



So when I send this json to the API :
{
        
        "name": "test",
        "type": {
            "id": 5,
            "org_type": "Wellness",
            "description": "test",
            "is_active": true
        },
        "address": "test",
        "unit_no": "test",
        "city": "test",
        "province": "test",
        "country": "test",
        "zip": "L5H 0Y2",
        "email": "org443@gmail.com",
        "phone1": "334-353-3453",
        "phone2": "333-333-3333",
        "subscription": "monthly",
        "credit_card": "3433-4444-5555-6666",
        "card_exp_date": "03/33",
        "card_cvv": 555,
        "is_active": true
    }

when I use
typeId = self.request.data.pop("type_id")
I get this error :
 typeId = self.request.data.pop("type_id")
KeyError: 'type_id'

and when I use
typeId = self.request.data.pop("type_id")
I get this error :
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got {'id': 5, 'org_type': 'Wellness', 'description': 'here is', 'is_active': True}.
